# When and how might a pilot use the 1-in-60 rule and the 10 degree drift rule for off track error corrections?

Tags: navigation

Okay, this is a 3 part question.

1. How would you use the 1 in 60 rule, in the air - in flight?
2. When would you use the 10° drift line way and when would you use the 1 in 60 rule way?
3. With reference to nav. flights, am I right in thinking that when you go on nav. flights, you can go with your map, so you can literally just look down at your (maybe folded) map and see the 10° lines drawn in?

(I'm specifically mentioning the 10° lines because there may be some follow up questions on that)

Answer (score 0):

I was taught the 10 degree drift line method and was encouraged not to fly by the chart. Rather, the method was to select your heading at a waypoint and fly for a reasonable amount of time, then review the chart.

Obviously it requires some features and judgement, but you'd then take out the chart and make a determination using the 10 degree lines as a guide. You can then use the double track error method to get back to your intended course.

Comment: Can you help me? I haven't flown a single nav. flight so I'm trying to get a better understanding of the world of navigation. And I wont lie, I'm struggling. It's like I have the information, but it's jumbled up, or I don't understand it fully, or something.              
- With reference to going off track during flight - to regain track or go straight to the destination - HOW would I execute the 10° line method and the 1 in 60 rule in the cockpit? And WHEN would I execute which one?